# Question about Roland 606 schematic

Tags: schematics

^
I have a question regarding the circuit diagram of the Roland 606.

I'm currently redrawing the hihat circuit with noise unit.

The symbol behind R6, and elsewhere in the schematic has this bulky explanation.

Can someone tell me what it means?

Petunia[image: 606 schematic question]

Comment: Is there another symbol like that on the schematic somewhere? It could just be a link between different parts of the schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding signal can be found here
[image: 606 schematic]
<sub>(source: [hyperreal.org](http://machines.hyperreal.org/manufacturers/Roland/TR-606/schematics/roland.TR-606.schem-5.gif))</sub>

It's 'leaving' right of D1, below the text "IC 1 HD14584B" and 'entering' where you highlighted it.

Below is indicated where the components are that are referred to in the text above. They are probably mounted for some types and left out for other types.

[image]

They can be found in the same sheet where you found the hihat part.
http://machines.hyperreal.org/manufacturers/Roland/TR-606/schematics/roland.TR-606.schem-6.gif

Comment: Ahh ok now I understand that, thanks.
The connection probably has something to do with the decay time being affected by the tempo.